# Structure of MPEG-4 "©xyz" box

Tags: metadata, mpeg4

*[This was originally posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77971906/structure-of-mpeg-4-xyz-box, and I was redirected to here. I understand if it is too OT and is closed.]*.

I am trying to parse out ISO/IEC 14496-12 based files (essentially MPEG-4 movies). There are a few boxes are not in the standards (or on the MP4 Registration Authority lists), but are in real-world files. They mostly pretty simple to trace to QuickTime or similar, where the implementation is just not updated.

I'm struggling with the GPS location box (`©xyz`).

Here is an example:

```
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1e, 0xa9, 0x78, 0x79, 0x7a,
0x00, 0x12, 0x15, 0xc7, 0x2b, 0x34, 0x31, 0x2e,
0x33, 0x37, 0x35, 0x38, 0x2b, 0x30, 0x30, 0x32,
0x2e, 0x31, 0x34, 0x39, 0x32, 0x2f
```

The first eight bytes are the box length and box name. No problem with that.

The next four bytes are the unknowns: `0x00, 0x12, 0x15, 0xc7`.

The remaining bytes are text "+41.3758+002.1492/" which is the expected
latitude and longitude (Barcelona) per ISO 6709 (albeit not the 2023 version).

Of the unknowns, I can interpret the first two bytes as a 16 bit (unsigned) integer which matches the number of characters in the text. That is guesswork though.

The next two are a mystery - could perhaps be constants since I see the same `0x15 0xc7` values when generated from a different device in Australia.

What is the defined structure for this box, and is there a published specification that defines that structure?

Comment: Looking at a video I have with exiftool and using the `-v4` option, which shows a breakdown of the structure, it seems that the character encoding and language should appear before the actual GPS data, but exiftool is showing 8 bytes instead of 4, and I can't seem to figure out what your 4 bytes mean.  I've posted an example output to [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/PgEi3b06) which includes a default entry and a French entry.  Hopefully, that can help.

Comment: Thanks. Over at the original stack overflow question, we traced it down to the language code (which a single pad bit, then three 5 bit numbers which are the difference from 0x60 to the ASCII value.